# Unrecognized argument format hosting.ini

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, asp.net-core

Trying to deploy default asp 5 app on to docker container running on ubuntu server. All goes smooth except one thing. Application cant start giving System.FormatException: Unrecognized argument format: 'hosting.ini'.

Any ideas? What is this about?

Comment: can you post a reproducer, Dockerfile, needed other files, `docker run` command?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 Community to deploy. A command used to deploy as VS goes: Executing command [docker -H tcp://192.168.163.132:4243/ run -t -d -p 80:8080 -e "server.urls=http://*:8080" webapp2].

Ubuntu is deployed as VMWare virtual machine. I can access images list URL at http://192.168.163.132:4243/images/json

A docker file created by VS:
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./kestrel"]

Comment: I can see image deployed, but trying to repro run and then read the logs i see mentioned exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing refs to hosting.ini. Replace that with direct instructions to run web and kestrel with specified URL.

Answer (score 0):

Open project.json file and look for this line:

"kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --serve**rM**icrosoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.ini"

There's a missing space between --server and Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel. Add a space there and publish will work.